# Concurrency problem with arrays (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency

For an algorithm I'm working on I tried to develop a blacklisting mechanism that can blacklist arrays in a specific way: If "1, 2, 3" is blacklisted "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" is also considered blacklisted.
I'm quite happy with the solution I've come up with so far. But there seem to be some serious problems when I access a blacklist from multiple threads. The method "contains" (see code below) sometimes returns true, even if an array is not blacklisted. This problem does not occur if I only use one thread, so it most likely is a concurrency problem.
I've tried adding some synchronization, but it didn't change anything. I also tried some slightly different implementations using java.util.concurrent classes. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
public class Blacklist {

private static final int ARRAY_GROWTH = 10;

private final Node root = new Node();

private static class Node{

    private volatile Node[] childNodes = new Node[ARRAY_GROWTH];

    private volatile boolean blacklisted = false;

    public void blacklist(){
        this.blacklisted = true;
        this.childNodes = null;
    }
}

public void add(final int[] array){

    synchronized (root) {

        Node currentNode = this.root;

        for(final int edge : array){
            if(currentNode.blacklisted)
                return;

            else if(currentNode.childNodes.length <= edge) {
                currentNode.childNodes = Arrays.copyOf(currentNode.childNodes, edge + ARRAY_GROWTH);
            }

            if(currentNode.childNodes[edge] == null) {
                currentNode.childNodes[edge] = new Node();
            }

            currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[edge];
        }

        currentNode.blacklist();
    }


}

public boolean contains(final int[] array){

    synchronized (root) {

        Node currentNode = this.root;

        for(final int edge : array){
            if(currentNode.blacklisted)
                return true;

            else if(currentNode.childNodes.length <= edge || currentNode.childNodes[edge] == null)
                return false;

            currentNode = currentNode.childNodes[edge];
        }

        return currentNode.blacklisted;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: It looks OK to me. The synchronization should prevent all problems from calling add and contains concurrently, so I guess your problem is on the code calling them. BTW, with synchronization you don't need to declare the variables in a node volatile.

Comment: It looks OK to me too :)
The variables are just volatile because I thought it might help. But it seems to make no difference if they're volatile or not.

Comment: Why blacklist method is public ? Are you sure no other thread call it ?

Comment: @Istao, the blacklist method is in the private inner class Node, nobody can call it unless they got a reference of the root Node (which they don't).

Comment: @Istao, it is in a private inner class, so no one can call it from outside - at least if the above is the complete definition of `Blacklist`. @Johannes, is this so?

Comment: @Péter Yes, it's the complete definition. I guess I could make the method private, but that's not really my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
I ran your code through a test suite with ten threads adding and comparing thousands of patterns, but I could find nothing wrong with your implementation.  I believe you are misinterpreting your data.  For example, in a threaded environment this will sometimes return false:

```
// sometimes this can be false
blacklist.contains(pattern) == blacklist.contains(pattern);
```

Another thread altered the blacklist between after the first call, but before the second call.  This is normal behaviour and the class itself can't do anything to stop it.  If this isn't the behaviour you want, you can synchronize it from outside of the class:

```
synchronized (blacklist) {
    // this will always be true
    blacklist.contains(pattern) == blacklist.contains(pattern);
}
```

**Original response:**
<s>You synchronize the root node, but this does not synchronize any of its children.  All you have to do to make your class bulletproof is synchronize the `add(int[])` and `contains(int[])` methods and then don't leak any references.  This ensures that only one thread can ever be using a Blacklist object at one time.</s>

I fiddled with your code while trying to make sense of it, so you might as well have it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Blacklist {
    private final Node root = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, false);

    public synchronized void add(int[] array) {
        if (array == null) return;
        Node next, cur = root;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1 && !cur.isLeaf(); i++) {
            next = cur.getChild(array[i]);

            if (next == null) { 
                next = new Node(array[i], false);
                cur.addChild(next);
            }

            cur = next;
        }

        if (!cur.isLeaf()) {
            next = cur.getChild(array[array.length-1]); 
            if (next == null || !next.isLeaf())
                cur.addChild(new Node(array[array.length-1], true));
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean contains(int[] array) {
        if (array == null) return false;
        Node cur = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            cur = cur.getChild(array[i]);
            if (cur == null) return false;
            if (cur.isLeaf()) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static class Node {
        private final Map<Integer, Node> children; 
        private final int value;

        public Node(int _value, boolean leaf) { 
            children = (leaf?null:new HashMap<Integer, Node>());
            value = _value;
        }

        public void addChild(Node child) { children.put(child.value, child); }
        public Node getChild(int value) { return children.get(value); }
        public boolean isLeaf() { return (children == null); }

    }
}
```

The [Collections framework](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) can make things a lot easier for you.  You're not doing yourself any favors by reimplementing ArrayList.

Here I use a HashMap so that you don't have to allocate over 9000 references for a something like this:

```
blacklist.add(new int[] {1, 2000, 3000, 4000});
```

Comment: "All you have to do make your class bulletproof is synchronize the add(int[]) and contains(int[]) methods and then don't leak any references." - and he has already done all this... from a nitpicky point of view, your synchronizing on the `Blacklist` object itself is actually more vulnerable than his synchronizing on the internal `root` object, as the latter is not visible to anyone outside, so only this `Blacklist` instance can lock on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works fine. Still not quite sure why, but I'll have a closer look at it tomorow.<br/>
And I know about the Collections framework. Just thought it might be slightly faster if I use a simple array :)<br/>
Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: The HashMap version performs roughly the same (~3% difference) for small numbers.  Your version takes more work to write, is harder to read, crashes on negative numbers, and runs out of heap space on large numbers. :)

Comment: Turns out your right. The real problem was, that an array got blacklisted by one thread while another one was still assuming it's not blacklisted. This did not occur with your solution, because it does not behave exactly like mine. Now that I know it's actually pretty obvious. Anyway, thanks again for your help. Long days and pleasent nights ;)

Comment: And may you have twice the number.